# SQLITE3 pass duplicate and wrong data in android fragment USING android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

A `word` project SQLITE3 used in android fragment pass the data of last tuple for several times. However, I rewrite the code in another project named `people` without using fragment works well. I wonder why this problem happens since the code of the data passing part are almost the same. BELOW are the data passing part of two projects.

### 1. problem in project: word

#### 1.1fragment

```
public class fragment_review extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private ArrayList<word> wordlist;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DBHelper dbHelper;
private View rootView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_fragment_review, container,false);
    manageDatabase();
    return rootView;
}

private void manageDatabase() {
    LinearLayout put_text = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store_sample_database);

    wordlist = new ArrayList<word>();

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from wordtable",null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String en_word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("en_word"));
        String meaning = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("meaning"));
        word w=new word(id, en_word, meaning);
        wordlist.add(w);
    }
    for (word w:wordlist) {

        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

        tv.setText(w.toString());
        tv.setTextSize(18);

        put_text.addView(tv);
    }
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

#### 1.2DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE wordtable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "en_word CHAR," +
        "meaning CHAR)";
String INSERT_DATA="INSERT INTO wordtable (id,en_word,meaning)";
String VALUES1 ="VALUES(1, '00N1','S1' )";
String VALUES2 ="VALUES(2, 'hvN2','S2' )";
String VALUES3 ="VALUES(3, 'N3','b kjbS3' )";
String VALUES4 ="VALUES(4, 'N4','xddfS4' )";
//build databse
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "word_2ed.db",null,1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //build table
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wordtable");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES1);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES2);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES3);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES4);

}
```

#### 1.3RESULT OF THE `word` PROJECT

[image: WRONG OUTPUT]

### 2 works fine in project: people

#### 2.1 MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<person> personList;
private MyOpenHelper myOpenHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initUI();
}


private void initUI() {//SAME AS THE manageDatabase() METHOD
    LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL);
    LinearLayout entry1 = findViewById(R.id.ll_first);
    LinearLayout entry2 = findViewById(R.id.ll_second);

    personList = new ArrayList<person>();

    myOpenHelper = new MyOpenHelper(this);
    db = myOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from person",null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String salary = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("salary"));
        String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone"));
        person p=new person(_id, name, salary, phone);
        personList.add(p);
    }
    for(person p:personList)
    {

        TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
        TextView tv2=new TextView(this);



        tv1.setText(p.toString1());
        tv1.setTextSize(18);
        tv2.setText(p.toString2());
        tv2.setTextSize(18);

        entry1.addView(tv1);
        entry2.addView(tv2);
    }

    }
    }
```

#### 2.2MyOpenHelper.java

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE person(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "name CHAR," +
        "salary CHAR," +
        "phone CHAR)";
String INSERT_DATA="INSERT INTO person (_id,name,salary,phone)";
String VALUES1 ="VALUES(1, 'N1','S1','P1' )";
String VALUES2 ="VALUES(2, 'N2','S2','P2' )";
String VALUES3 ="VALUES(3, 'N3','S3','P3' )";
String VALUES4 ="VALUES(4, 'N4','S4','P4' )";
public MyOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "people.db",null,1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES1);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES2);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES3);
    db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA+VALUES4);

}
```

Comment: Methods `manageDatabase()` in **1.1** and `initUI()`  in **2.1** are same, but I cannot get the right result in 1.1, where the duplicate output is shown in img 1.3. How can I fix this ? I checked and compared, but I cannot find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged and found that attributes in `word` were defined as `public` while attributrs in `people` are defined as private. Solution is change public to private. (I didn't show these code here). Or else the public attributes will change after the new object created. Though I'm not very clear why public cause this change of Arraylist.